# Sufficient conditions for stability of numerical schemes for PDE?

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, transport-equation

I've got this numerical scheme for the 1D linear advection equation $u_t + au_x = 0$: $$\dfrac{U_{j, n+1} - U_{j, n}}{\Delta t} + a \dfrac{U_{j+2, n} - U_{j+1, n}}{\Delta x} = 0.$$ Tried von Neumann analysis but got $a \Delta t / \Delta x \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow \lambda > 1$. If I understand correctly, the CFL condition is $a < 0$, $a\Delta t/\Delta x \in [-1, 0)$. So what are other available analyses to determine the range of $a\Delta t/\Delta x$ so that the scheme will be stable? Thanks in advance.

Edit: tried error analysis that denote the error at $x_j, t_{n+1} = e_{j, n+1} = U_{j, n+1} - u(x_j, t_{n+1})$, and then $|e_{j, n+1}| \leq (1 + k)\max(|e_{j, n}|, |e_{j+1, n}|, |e_{j+2, n}|) + |T_{j, n}| \Delta t = \cdots \leq \sum_{i = 0}^n (1 + k)^i |T_{j, n}|\Delta t$, where $k = -a\Delta t/\Delta x > 0$, and $T_{j, n}$ is the time-related truncation error, but I cannot make sure the $\sum_{i = 0}^n (1 + k)^i$ is bounded...

Comment: You'll need to specify the boundary condition. Note that the advection equation requires a boundary condition at one end, and then only one sign of $a$ ($\pm$) works for said boundary condition. So to say 'the CFL condition is $a < 0$...' doesn't really make sense without the aforementioned information.

Comment: I have no boundary conditions; I jotted the data points, observed and decided $a < 0$ to have the scheme possibly converge. In case I need to specify, I'm referring to the stability of the numerical scheme.

Comment: If you have no boundary conditions, then your problem is ill posed and I'm not sure how you expect any scheme to be stable. Also, I don't know what you mean by 'I jotted the data points, observed and decided $a < 0$ to have the scheme possibly converge'. You observed _what_ exactly? Perhaps you should look at [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/boundary-conditions-for-the-advection-equation-discretized-by-a-finite-differenc) and [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5425/strange-oscillation-when-solving-the-advection-equation-by-finite-difference-wit).

Comment: I observed that $U_{j, n+1}$ depends on $U_{j, n}, U_{j+1, n}$ and $U_{j+2, n}$, thus the domain of dependence at each data point is on the (lower) right hand side, so I said $a < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the discretized PDE should read for $a<0$
$$ \frac{U_j^{n+1} - U_j^n}{\Delta t} + a \frac{U^n_{\color{red}{j + 1}} - U^n_{\color{red} j }}{\Delta x} = 0.$$

A detailed proof why the CFL condition
$$ | a | \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x} \leq 1$$
implies stability is given in [this Lecture Notes, Lemma 2.3](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2013/math/nhdgl/numcl_notes_HOMEPAGE.pdf).
This proof is for periodic or zero boundary conditions.